# Problem with partition (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, windows-7

I created bootable USB Windows for my UBUNTU but when i installed it, it says:

"Windows Setup Cannot find a location to store temporary installation files. To install Windows, make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at least 502 megabytes (MB) of free space."

I do not actually have anything files on my laptop. please help me! where can i see that partition. i can't see it in my laptop with ubuntu OS.

Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: It's because your hard drive is formatted as an ext4. You must delete the partition and create a new ntfs one.

Comment: Thank you Rohith. it's you again. I already did the BOOTABLE USB WINDOWS. indeed, thank you for that one.Honestly, i am not familiar with UBUNTU. I don't actually know how to delete the partition and create a new ntfs as well. Can you teach me how? please? thank you.

Comment: I also tried to delete the partition. it says: "Error deleting partition. Devise is busy" how?

Answer (score 0):

Create an unallocated partition for installation of the windows and try. Try Gparted to reallocating the partitions.

Comment: i also tried to create but i didn't work. it says, unformatted. can you please teach me step by step. thank you.